# Python int too large to convert to C long code needs fix

Tags: python, matrix, overflow

Hey guys I keep getting this error when I run my code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Jacobi.py", line 93, in <module>
    limit, guess, statement = jacobi(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
  File "Jacobi.py", line 65, in jacobi
    guess[0, i] = guess2[0, i]
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

I posted my code below, anybody got a quick fix? It doesn't do this all the time just in random cases. Anybody know why?

```
def jacobi(file_name, tolIn):

if file_name is None:
    exit()

#Turns file into one big matrix
A = np.loadtxt(file_name, dtype=int64, delimiter=" ")
aRows = int(A.shape[0])
aCols = int(A.shape[1])
bdim = (aRows, 1)
b = np.zeros(bdim)

s = raw_input("Please provide list of your guess values separated by spaces, e.g. 1 2 3: ")
guess = np.matrix(s)

#Creates nx1 b matrix
for j in range(0, aRows):
   b[j,0] = float(A[j, aCols-1])
```

#Creates A matrix
    elim = [aCols-1]
    N = np.delete(A, elim, 1)
    A = N

```
for i in range (0, A.shape[0]):
    for k in range (0, A.shape[0]):
        A[i,k] = round((A[i,k]),7)
print(A)
print ('\n')
print(b)


tol = float(tolIn)

#Sets intial previous guess so loop does not stop first try
prevGuess = np.zeros((1, aRows))
for i in range (0, aRows):
    prevGuess[0,i] = 1000


guess2 = np.zeros((1, aRows))
limit = 0
aRows = int(A.shape[0])
aCols = int(A.shape[1])


while ((np.linalg.norm(guess - prevGuess) > tol) and limit < 100):
    for j in range (0, aRows):
        guess2[0,j] = b[j,0]
        for i in range (0, aCols):
            if (i != j):
                guess2[0,j] = round((guess2[0,j] -(A[j,i]) * (guess[0,i])), 7)
        guess2[0,j] = round((guess2[0,j] / A[j,j]), 7)

    for i in range(0, aCols):
            prevGuess[0,i] = guess[0, i]
    for i in range(0, aCols-1):
            guess[0, i] = round((guess2[0, i]), 7)
    guess2 = np.zeros((1, aCols))
    limit = limit + 1

#answers mod 2 to get real answers
#for i in range(0,aCols):
#    guess[0,i] = guess[0,i]%2

#print ('\n')
#print(limit)
#print ('\n')
#print (guess)
#print ('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `range()` requires the max number to be contained within a c integer range. If you want to get around this, you can use `itertools.count()`. It starts at 0 (or the number you pass as a parameter) and counts forever (or until you break).

Example:

```
for i in itertools.count():
    if i == 10:
        break
    print i
```

docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count

Comment: but it works for other codes, it has to do with the files im inputting. One has decimals, the other just has straight intergers.

Comment: Unfortunately for me there's a lot of your code that's not described in the question, so I can only guess what each part does. Also I can't test it myself. Could you maybe give examples of inputs, outputs, and what you expect? That would help me understand a lot better.

Comment: inputs are a .dat file containg value that I load into a matrix using load.txt. I've used files with straight integers and it worked fine, I have a file with long decimals and it throws that message. I'll edit the post with my whole code.

Comment: Have you manually checked that your input is less than the size of an integer? That size will vary depending on your python installation being 32bit or 64bit.